# Effect on the current by power factor correction

Tags: power-supply, power

When I make the power factor close to one, does the current in the circuit Change?

Comment: Why else would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passive approach to grid power factor correction is shown with a variable capacitor.

In reality, they switch racks of Polyurethane 3-phase capacitors or oil filled if older.

[A picture is more than a thousand words.  What is your answer in uF?](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%207.010541234668786%2028%205%2050%0Av%20400%20304%20400%20176%200%201%2050%20330%200%201.5707963267948966%200.5%0Ar%20400%20112%20400%20176%200%200.1%0Ac%20560%20112%20560%20304%200%200.000001%20-327.70354667150633%0Aw%20400%20304%20464%20304%200%0A403%20608%20176%20736%20240%200%202_64_0_4354_640_0.00625_0_2_2_3%0A403%20608%20256%20736%20320%200%202_64_0_4353_5_0.2_0_2_2_3%0A403%20416%20-16%20544%2032%200%201_64_0_4355_2.5_25.6_0_2_1_3%0A403%20416%2048%20544%20112%200%201_64_0_4353_5_25.6_0_2_1_3%0A403%20192%20176%20320%20240%200%200_64_0_20739_640_51.2_0_2_0_3%0A403%20192%20240%20320%20304%200%200_64_0_4353_5_25.6_0_2_0_3%0A403%20608%2096%20736%20160%200%202_64_7_4354_5_0.1_0_1_40%0A403%20416%20-96%20544%20-32%200%201_64_7_4354_5_0.1_0_1_80%0A403%20192%2032%20320%20160%200%200_64_7_53514_5_0.1_0_1_20480%0A403%20416%20320%20544%20352%200%203_64_0_4354_0.0000762939453125_0.1_0_2_3_3%0A403%20416%20352%20544%20400%200%203_64_0_4353_0.0000762939453125_25.6_0_2_3_3%0Al%20512%20112%20512%20304%200%200.1%20-1.0473978275961928%0A403%20752%20256%20880%20320%200%2015_64_0_4353_0.0000762939453125_25.6_0_2_15_3%0A403%20752%20176%20880%20240%200%2015_64_0_4355_640_12.8_0_2_15_3%0A403%20752%2096%20880%20160%200%2015_64_7_4354_5_0.1_0_1_5120%0Aw%20512%20304%20560%20304%200%0Aw%20512%20112%20560%20112%200%0Ax%20604%2043%20946%2046%204%2014%20Adjust%5CsCapacitance%5Csslider%5Csto%5Csget%5CsPF%5Cq1%5Cswhat%5Csvalue%5Csis%5Csit?%0Ax%20607%2071%20977%2074%204%2014%20Scope%5Cstrace%5Csis%5Csdifferential%5Csacross%5Cseach%5Cspart.%5CsSliders%5Cson%5Csside%0Ax%20603%20339%20688%20342%204%2014%20Ideal%5CsInductor%0Ax%20770%20338%20865%20341%204%2014%20ideal%5CsCapacitor%0Ax%20709%20-83%20966%20-80%204%2014%20Tony%5CsStewart%5Cs,%5Csnear%5CsToronto%5Csretired%5CsEE75%0Ar%20464%20304%20464%20112%200%2030%0Aw%20400%20112%20464%20112%200%0Aw%20464%20304%20512%20304%200%0Aw%20464%20112%20512%20112%200%0Ax%20421%20-108%20499%20-105%204%2014%20Load%5CsR%5Cq100%0Ax%20789%20-108%20967%20-105%204%2014%20Ideal%5CsInductor%5Cs%5Cs%5CsDec%5Cs21%5Cs2019%0A38%202%200%200.000001%200.000101%20Capacitance%0A)  Then how much peak current and peak power did you save in the power source?  How much average?

[image]

The winner gets 200 free LEDs > 16,000 mcd @ 20mA 5mm if you send a self-address envelope.

Comment: For fun you can drag the Cap off and put it back and the power transient

Answer (score 1):

Power factor correction has today 2 different areas. The older (and still valid) meaning was to compensate the reactive power when loads were partially inductive or capasitive. Today the other meaning is to keep the current sinusoidal and in phase with the supplied AC voltage. All kind of power supplies and triac power controllers tend to sip non-sinusoidal current and that causes problems in power distribution networks which are optimized for linear loads.

In the older case one inserts a capacitor in parallel with inductive load and the total current decreases because inductive reactive current component is compensated by 180 degrees phase shifted current throug the capacitor. The result is the same if a capacitive load gets an inductor in parallel.

PFC circuits which try to eliminate harmonic spectral components of the current and make the apparent load resistive (=non reactive) do the same as the traditional compensators and in addition they remove distortion harmonics from the current. So they reduce the current in two ways.

Of course one can make power factor closer to 1  also in an idiotic way. Let's assume your motor is quite inductive and draws 1 ampere from mains AC. Your total load becomes less inductive if you add a high power resistor in parallel with the motor and that resistor soaks 10 amperes.